# in Emacs, how to get rid of "possible archaic use of (hi-lock-mode)" error?

Tags: emacs

I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 on OSX. When I start Emacs I get this error:

```
Warning (emacs): Possible archaic use of (hi-lock-mode).
Use (global-hi-lock-mode 1) in .emacs to enable hi-lock for all buffers,
use (hi-lock-mode 1) for individual buffers.  For compatibility with Emacs
versions before 22 use the following in your init file:

        (if (functionp 'global-hi-lock-mode)
            (global-hi-lock-mode 1)
          (hi-lock-mode 1))
```

According to rgrep, I do not have the string `hi-lock` in my `~/.emacs.d` folder anywhere. I don't have a Backtrace because it appears in `*Warnings*` not in `Backtrace`.

How can I track down the culprit and get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Recursively bisect your init file to find which part of it leads to the warning. If the culprit is just code that loads another library, then recursively bisect it similarly, to locate the source.

   To recursively bisect a file, I recommend command `comment-region`, which I bind to `C-x C-;`. You can use it to comment or uncomment blocks of text etc.  Comment out 1/2 of the file, then 3/4, then 7/8 etc. until you narrow it down completely. This is a binary search, so it is very quick.
2. You can also, of course, `grep` the source code you use (load) for, say, `hi-lock`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Drew's excellent suggestions above, the simplest thing is probably to add `(debug-on-entry #'warn)` at the top of the init file to actually get the backtrace you want.

I had a call to a function that called function `hi-lock-face-buffer` (alias `highlight-regexp`) in my init file, and it produced this warning, spurious in this case. The warning is only triggered while in the `*scratch*` buffer while loading a library, so interactive use of the same function doesn't cause it.